# Execution Plan StatementText contains incorrect syntax

Tags: sql-server, execution-plan, dynamic-sql, syntax

I have run an execution plan with management studio 2014 on mssql 2008 R2. 
To be able to better read the Selectstatement i right-clicked the plan to view it in xml.

I noticed that some statements seem to contain invalid charachters `SELECT @IsHeadVersion = IsHead&#xD;&#xA;FROM myTable`. At least if i copy them into a new query window i get an invalid syntax error

```
  <StmtSimple StatementCompId="10" StatementEstRows="1" 
  StatementId="2" StatementOptmLevel="TRIVIAL" 
  StatementSubTreeCost="0.0032831" 
  StatementText="SELECT @IsHeadVersion = IsHead&#xD;&#xA;FROM myTable
   WHERE Id = @VersionID&#xD;&#xA;&#xD;&#xA;
  -- if head  and no delta, select platformIDs and vehicleIDs in this version&#xD;" 
   StatementType="SELECT" QueryHash="0x29CDF8384A77017F" QueryPlanHash="0xF39275675F085D1B">
   <StatementSetOptions ANSI_NULLS="true" ANSI_PADDING="true" 
        ANSI_WARNINGS="true" ARITHABORT="true" 
        CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL="true" 
        NUMERIC_ROUNDABORT="false" QUOTED_IDENTIFIER="true" />
```

The Statment is dynamically generated inside a stored procedure.

My qustion is could the invalid characters be added by management studio in the xml view?

Or do i have incorrect escape sequences inside the generated sql

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<sub>*Community Wiki answer generated from question comments*</sub>

These are not "invalid characters". This is a side-effect of formatting the plan as XML; some characters have special meaning in XML and must be encoded.

To read the query text:

1. Save the XML plan as a `*.sqlplan` file
2. Reopen it in SQL Server Management Studio
3. Right click in the plan window and select "Edit Query Text...":

   [image: Screenshot]

Comment: Please note "Edit Query Text" has limit of 4000 chars and it will display 1st 4000 char only. This https://sqlserverfast.com/blog/hugo/2018/03/ssms-hidden-gem-edit-query-text/ might help with more details.

Answer (score 2):

`&#xD;&#xA;` are carriage return/line feed. You could use SSMS find/replace to either remove them, or set them to start new lines. Just use the regular expression option.
[image: Replacing data using regular expressions]